# SVG Text doesn't update on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, svg, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic framework for my android app.

On my index I have a SVG Text along a path that will update with a new text on a button click.
On ionic server its OK and functional, but when I upload to the emulator the text simply doesn't update anymore.

Here is my code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="svg" width="240px" height="63px" viewBox="-36.745 72.133 245.331 23.568">
    <defs>
        <path id="MyPath" d="M-36.745,89.659c0,0,17.786,8.625,51.934,0.671c0,0,97.811-22.88,152.395-14.463c0,0,20.615,5.33,40.871,15"/>
    </defs>
    <text>
        <textPath class="svgText" xlink:href="#MyPath"> 
            SVG TEXT THAT NEED UPDATE
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
==========

<button id="cardApply" ng-click="updateText()">Update</button>

==========
updateText = function($title){
    var svgNewTitle = $title;

    $('.svgText').html(svgNewTitle);

};
```

Please just ignore the fact that I'm not using the Angular "goodies", I'm new to its "ways" and couldn't make it work properly. Jquery was the only way to make it work.

The SVG text doesn't update on an android browser.

Comment: @RobertLongson 
like this: $('.svgText').textContent(svgNewTitle)??

On desktop it fire an error..

Comment: I also tried 

$('.svgText').textContent = svgNewTitle;

But didn't work as well... :(

Comment: THANKS @RobertLongson worket like a charm!!! :D :D Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to write this as

```
$('.svgText')[0].textContent = svgNewTitle;
```

That's rather more portable than trying to use the .html() function. The [0] converts the jQuery object to a raw DOM object.

Comment: you know anything about how can I solve this problem here? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983568/drag-and-resize-image-inside-canvas-mobile

I'm totally lost.. :/

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking another question indicating which issue you still need help with. Try to make it as narrow as possible and show how far you've got with the solution as you did with this question and you're more likely to get an answer.